# X11 configuration on Ubuntu 18.04. Worked on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, x11, x11forwarding

Here is a script which is run in cron for user1 who has sudo privileges

```
   export DISPLAY=:0 
   export XAUTHORITY=/home/user2/.Xauthority 
   scrot -q 30 "/tmp/%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M_screen.jpg" 2>/tmp/err
```

It worked fine on Ubuntu 16.04. When upgraded to 18:04, it gives the error: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keygiblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?

File .Xauthority is owned by user2, group owned by user1 and has permissions 660.

What changed between Ubuntu 16:04 and 18:04? I tried **export DISPLAY=:1.0** instead of  **export DISPLAY=:0** after reading a post on SO. It gave this error: *giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Invalid_MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1_key_when_trying_to_run_a_program_as_root):

> **Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key when trying to run a program as root**
>
> That error means that only the current user has access to the X server. The solution is to give access to root:
>
> `$ xhost +si:localuser:root`
>
> That line can also be used to give access to X to a different user than root.

So you probably need to execute on the host:

`$ xhost +si:localuser:user1`

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks. But why was it working on 16.04 without this line? 18.04 broke a few things for me. netplan for one...

Comment: I doubt that the x11 authentication mechanism changed dramatically between Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Most likely that setting was set manually on the 16.04 system or set by a script not present in 18.04.